# How to make an image center (vertically & horizontally) inside a bigger div

Tags: html, css

I have a div 200 x 200 px. I want to place a 50 x 50 px image right in the middle of the div.

How can it be done?

I am able to get it centered horizontally by using `text-align: center` for the div. But vertical alignment is the issue..

Comment: Here are two simple methods to center an element within a div, vertically, horizontally or both (pure CSS): http://stackoverflow.com/a/31977476/3597276

Comment: http://programmerscando.com/how-to-get-an-image-centered-using-css/

here is quick method for doing this for img tag.

Answer (score 337, accepted):

Personally, I'd place it as the background image within the div, the CSS for that being:

```
#demo {
    background: url(bg_apple_little.gif) no-repeat center center;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

(Assumes a div with `id="demo"` as you are already specifying `height` and `width` adding a `background` shouldn't be an issue)

Let the browser take the strain.

Comment: This is usually the best answer, unless the size of the image can vary from smaller to bigger than the container's size. In the 'smaller' case, it will be fine, but in the 'bigger' case, your image will be clipped.

Comment: Not as SEO/reader friendly if you want to add an ALT attribute.

Comment: What about if we are using a sprite? I am trying to center the background image, but I'm using a  CSS sprite. Any ideas?

Comment: @Nathan this is not an easy task. You can do it though if you know the exact dimensions of the div and leave enough transparent space around the image on the sprite so that the other images on the sprite are not displayed.

Comment: Here is a better solution: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/exactly-center-an-imagediv-horizontally-and-vertically/. Also suggested by @Tim K.

Comment: My images are always have a different size, How to applied this when image have different different size ?

Comment: @Anirugu use left: 50%  instead

Answer (score 451):

*Working in old browsers (IE >= 8)*

Absolute position in combination with automatic margin permits to center an element horizontally and vertically. The element position could be based on a parent element position using relative positioning. [View Result](https://jsfiddle.net/stuttufu/sj2m0oo2/1/)

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: this indeed centers img in the middle of the page, but not in the middle of the 200px x 200px div.

Comment: just make the div relative `#someDiv { position: relative }`

Comment: works well in all browsers the accepted doesn't work for IE < 9

Comment: This worked great for me, and helps when you do not have the exact size of either the container DIV or the image.   Thanks!

Comment: @AbhishekDeb and the last 20+ google results I went through to find out how to achieve this.

Comment: You can also center exclusively horizontal by omitting the top and bottom, and center exclusively vertical by omitting the right and left.

Comment: doesn't work in Opera 11.62 Build 1347 win7-64 (as of Okt.2014)

Comment: disadvantage of this approach: You cannot force the image to shrink from to the parent width any more, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/13546011/1627888

Comment: @YoLudke, yes, you can. just include `max-width:100%; height:auto;`. you can also make it aligned to any of the sides by omitting that side. pretty cool.

Comment: even now, with flex gaining popularity, this seems to be the only solution to allow proper vertical and horizontal alignment for the image in all major browsers. brilliant solution!

Comment: here's a fiddle demonstrating this method that might be helpful: http://jsfiddle.net/spencerw/pzvq72gb/

Comment: Doesn't work on images with dynamic width (thumbnails). The "position: absolute;" does somehow block the expansion

Comment: What's a dynamic width thumbnail? Can you post an example?

Comment: This solution can add "max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%;" to make image perfectly fit div.

Comment: Instead of putting `top: 0;`, `left: 0;`, etc., you can set `inset: 0;`, and it will do all of those.

Answer (score 110):

another way is to create a `table` with `valign`, of course. This would work regardless of you knowing the div's height or not.

```
<div>
   <table width="100%" height="100%" align="center" valign="center">
   <tr><td>
      <img src="foo.jpg" alt="foo" />
   </td></tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

but you should always stick to just `css` whenever possible.

Comment: I knew that this would get me down-voted. I thought about listing this just for the sake of completeness, but, oh well.

Comment: Don't you know that using tables causes blindness?

Comment: CSS when possible, but this is definitely a useful fallback. Don't forget why we stopped using tables in the first place. Use whatever is the most *flexible* solution. Sometimes this is it.

Comment: **Note:** This may have been "acceptable" in 2008, but in 2012, this is **never, ever** acceptable.

Comment: Objection, animuson:  All the other solutions here assume that you know the image size as they appear in the browser, which is not the case if you design a responsive layout where your image is "**height**:100%" and it's container is "**width**:25%", leaving you with an x or y margin of unknown size.

Comment: People who are blindly stupid to the usefulness of tables, shouldn't be in the business of building websites. This answer is perfectly valid, because there are STILL faults to CSS and wide-browser support.

Comment: such unnecessary dogma for killing tables over css...

Answer (score 81):

I would set your larger div with `position:relative;` then for your image do this:

```
img.classname{
   position:absolute;
   top:50%;
   left:50%;
   margin-top:-25px;
   margin-left:-25px;
}
```

This only works because you know the dimensions of both the image and the containing div. This will also let you have other items within the containing div... where solutions like using line-height will not.

**EDIT**: Note... your margins are negative half of the size of the image.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/exactly-center-an-imagediv-horizontally-and-vertically/

Comment: I used this, but removed `margin` bits and adding `-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
 -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
 -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
 transform: translateY(-50%);`. Gives more generic solution that does need element size.

Comment: Tried this it moves the image up if smaller than the div.

Answer (score 65):

This works correctly:

```
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto
```

else try this if the above only gives you horizontal centering:

```
.outerContainer {
   position: relative;
}

.innerContainer {
   width: 50px; //your image/element width here
   height: 50px; //your image/element height here
   overflow: auto;
   margin: auto;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Or use `display: block; margin: auto;` for the simplest.

Answer (score 57):

Use [Flexbox](https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties):

```css
.outerDiv {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;  /* Centering y-axis */
  align-items :center; /* Centering x-axis */
}
```

Comment: Nice! This actually worked and helps if you can't place the image as background, as suggested in the previous answer.

Answer (score 41):

here's another method to center everything within anything.

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/9VRxn/2/)

**HTML:** (simple as ever)

```
<div class="Container">
    <div class="Content"> /*this can be an img, span, or everything else*/
        I'm the Content
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.Container
{
    text-align: center;
}

    .Container:before
    {
        content: '';
        height: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

.Content
{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

### Benefits

The Container and Content height are unknown.

Centering without specific negative margin, without setting the line-height (so it works well with multiple line of text) and without a script, also Works great with CSS transitions.

Comment: +1. Great solution and very good SO answer. I'm wondering what's causing the browser to do the (expected) behaviour only by adding the `before` pseudoclass with `content: ""` (Because many of us might have tried `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: middle` without success).

Comment: it's actually very simple. you create an empty element inside the container that spans `100%` height, and then you align your element with the center of this empty one. causing your element to be in the exact center of the container.

Answer (score 31):

This is coming a bit late, but here's a solution I use to vertical align elements within a parent div.

**This is useful for when you know the size of the container div, but not that of the contained image.** (this is frequently the case when working with lightboxes or image carousels).

Here's the styling you should try:

```
 container div
 {
   display:table-cell;
   vertical-align:middle;

   height:200px;
   width:200px;
 }

 img
 {
   /*Apply any styling here*/        
 }
```

Comment: +1 for showing me a away to make a CSS div behave like a table cell, now I can avoid further countless hours of frustration getting CSS to do what is simple to do with a traditional HTML table cell

Comment: add in text-align:center; to container div and it's centered both directions if you're applying a max height/width to an unknown sized image.

Comment: best answer in my opinion. and dont forget the text-align: center;

Comment: Note: By default img elements are inline and will need to be set to 'block' to be in vertical middle. `img { display: block; }`

Comment: This answer seems better than the oter ones who that got more votes. It works regardless of third-party frameworks or combination of styles in multiple elements.

Answer (score 21):

I've found that Valamas' and Lepu's answers above are the most straightforward answers that deal with images of unknown size, or of known size that you'd rather not hard-code into your CSS. I just have a few small tweaks: remove irrelevant styles, size it to 200px to match the question, and add max-height/max-width to handle images that may be too large.

```
div.image-thumbnail
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}
div.image-thumbnail img
{
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-height: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

in the div

```
style="text-align:center; line-height:200px"
```

Comment: But this doesnt seem to work if the div just contains the image (FF3). 
code:
<div style="border: 1px solid #ccc; margin: 20px; height: 200px; width: 200px;">
<img src="sun.gif" />
</div>

Am I missing anything?

Comment: This does not really do what the question asked and is only supposed to work for text (and only centers the aimage/text vertically) The accepted answer is the most apropriate solution afaik.

Answer (score 13):

We can easily achieve this using `flex`. no need for `background-image`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <style>
      #image-wrapper{
         width:500px;
         height:500px;
         border:1px solid #333;
         display:flex;
         justify-content:center;
         align-items:center;
      }
   </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="image-wrapper">
<img id="myImage" src="http://blog.w3c.br/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/css31-213x300.png">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 12):

Vertical-align is one of the most misused css styles. It doesn't work how you might expect on elements that are not td's or css "display: table-cell".

This is a very good post on the matter. http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html

The most common methods to acheive what you're looking for are:

- padding top/bottom
- position absolute
- line-height

Answer (score 12):

In CSS do it as:

```
img
{

  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: Thats only make it horizontal center. If you provide auto for top and bottom margin, browsers take it as zero by default.

Comment: Doesn't work - http://jsfiddle.net/dandv/umBRF/, though the reason is not the margin-top/bottom as knoxxs suggests.

For the image to display as a table-cell, it needs a *parent* element to have `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;` - http://jsfiddle.net/dandv/umBRF/1/

Comment: Close, but the display and vertical-align properties need to be applied to the container, not the thing being centered. (See Kshitij Chopra's answer)

Answer (score 11):

@sleepy You can easily do this using the following attributes:

```css
#content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#myImage {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;  
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <img id="myImage" src="http://blog.w3c.br/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/css31-213x300.png">
</div>
```

References: [W3](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html)

Answer (score 9):

I have a gallery of images for which I don't know the exact heights or widths of images beforhand, I just know that they are smaller than the div in which they are going to be contained.

By doing a combination of **line-height** settings on the container and using **vertical-align:middle** on the image element, I finally got it to work on FF 3.5, Safari 4.0 and IE7.0 using the following HTML markup and the following CSS.

The HTML Markup

```
<div id="gallery">
    <div class="painting">
        <a href="Painting/Details/2">
            <img src="/Content/Images/Paintings/Thumbnail/painting_00002.jpg" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="painting">
        ...
    </div>
    ...
 </div>
```

The CSS

```
div.painting
{
    float:left;

    height:138px; /* fixed dimensions */
    width: 138px;

    border: solid 1px white;
    background-color:#F5F5F5;


    line-height:138px;    
    text-align:center;

}

    div.painting a img
    {
        border:none;
        vertical-align:middle;

    }
```

Answer (score 8):

Typically, I'll set the `line-height` to be 200px.  Usually does the trick.

Answer (score 6):

This works for me :

```
<body>
  <table id="table-foo">
    <tr><td>
        <img src="foo.png" /> 
    </td></tr>
  </table>
</body>
<style type="text/css">
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
  }
  #table-foo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  #table-foo img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 6):

[This is an old solution](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html) but browser market shares have advanced enough that you may be able to get by without the IE hack part of it if you are not concerned about degrading for IE7. This works when you know the dimensions of the outer container but may or may not know the dimensions of the inner image.

```
.parent {
    display: table;
    height: 200px; /* can be percentages, too, like 100% */
    width: 200px; /* can be percentages, too, like 100% */
}

.child {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```
 <div class="parent">
     <div class="child">
         <img src="foo.png" alt="bar" />
     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Another way (not mentioned here yet) is with [Flexbox](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/).

Just set the following rules on the container `div`:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
align-items: center; /* align vertical */
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/p6c5hcft/1/)**

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /* align horizontal */
  align-items: center;
  /* align vertical */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/food" alt="" />
</div>
```

A good place to start with Flexbox to see some of it's features and get syntax for maximum browser support is [flexyboxes](http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/)

Also, browser support nowadays is quite good: [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

For cross-browser compatibility for `display: flex` and `align-items`, you can use the following:

```
display: -webkit-box;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-align: center;
-ms-flex-align: center;
-webkit-align-items: center;
align-items: center;
```

Answer (score 5):

easy

```
img {
    transform: translate(50%,50%);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I've been trying to get an image to be centered vertically and horizontally within a circle shape using hmtl and css.

After combining several points from this thread, here's what I came up with: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jord8on/0ku2z8sx/)

Here's another example of this within a three column layout: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jord8on/4044sa60/)

**CSS:**

```
#circle {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: #A7A9AB;
-moz-border-radius: 50px;
-webkit-border-radius: 50px;
border-radius: 50px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
}

.images {
position: absolute;
margin: auto;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="circle">
<img class="images" src="https://png.icons8.com/facebook-like-filled/ios7/50" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can set position of image is align center horizontal by this

```
#imageId {
   display: block;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right:auto;
}
```

Comment: User needs alignment for both positions, this only solves half his question and, depending on the context of your code, not even that.

Answer (score 3):

You can center an image horizontally and vertically with the code below (works in IE/FF).
It will put the top edge of the image at exactly 50% of the browser height, and the margin-top(pulling half the height of the image up) will center it perfectly.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #middle {position: absolute; top: 50%;} /* for explorer only*/
    #middle[id] {vertical-align: middle; width: 100%;}
         #inner {position: relative; top: -50%} /* for explorer only */
</style>


<body style="background-color:#eeeeee">
    <div id="middle">
        <div id="inner" align="center" style="margin-top:...px"> /* the number will be half the height of your image, so for example if the height is 500px then you will put 250px for the margin-top */
            <img src="..." height="..." width="..." />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

I love jumping on old bandwagons!

**Here's a 2015 update to this answer**.  I started using CSS3 `transform` to do my dirty work for positioning.  This allows you to not have to make any extra HTML, you don't have to do math (finding half-widths of things) you can use it on any element!

Here's an example (with fiddle at the end).  Your HTML:

```
<div class="bigDiv">
    <div class="smallDiv">
    </div>
</div>
```

With accompanying CSS:

```
.bigDiv {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#efefef;
    position:relative;
}
.smallDiv {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#cc0000;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

What I do a lot these days is I will give a class to things I want centered and just re-use that class every time. For example:

```
<div class="bigDiv">
    <div class="smallDiv centerThis">
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.bigDiv {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#efefef;
    position:relative;
}
.smallDiv {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#cc0000;
}
.centerThis {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

This way, I will always be able to center something in it's container.  You just have to make sure that the thing you want centered is in a container that has a `position` defined.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/98pcz3qL/)

BTW: This works for centering BIGGER divs inside SMALLER divs as well.

Answer (score 2):

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  
  border: 3px solid green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

img { 
  position: relative;
  
  border: 3px solid red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.center {    
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <img class="center" src="http://placeholders.org/250/000/fff" />
</div>
```

Related: [Center a image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16702881/center-image-vertical-and-horizontal/46375063#46375063)

Answer (score 1):

thanks to everyone else for the clues.

I used this method

```
div.image-thumbnail
{
    width: 85px;
    height: 85px;
    line-height: 85px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
div.image-thumbnail img
{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use positioning. The following worked for me:

```
div{
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 200px; 
    height: 200px;  
    position: relative;
}
div img{
    width: 50px; 
    height: 50px;   
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.container {
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
float:left;
position:relative;
}
.children-with-img {
position: absolute;
width:50px;
height:50px;
left:50%;
top:50%;
transform:translate(-50%);
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the size of the parent div and the image, you can just use absolute positioning.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, it's nothing more than a hint.

Comment: Potato, potato.  I think it is an answer, although maybe not a great one.

Comment: How do you figure this answers the question?  At best, the OP knows that they'll have to look at another answer to figure out what this means (like [this answer that was posted almost a full hour before yours](http://stackoverflow.com/a/388190/1652962).  At worst, it's useless noise.

Comment: I think you're underestimating the best case.  In the best case, the OP knows what absolute positioning is, and can implement it directly.  I do agree that it seems rather pointless for this answer to exist, given that it doesn't seem to add much to previous ones.  I don't remember what I was thinking.  It's been a while!

Comment: Answers that attempt to answer the question are still answers. If you don't like an answer or think that an answer is wrong, down-vote the answer. Maybe you'll be able to shame the answer's answerer into deleting their own answer. [When to flag an answer as “it is not an answer”?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-it-is-not-an-answer/265553#265553)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Add this to image css:

```
img
{
   display: block;
   margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in HTML5 using CSS3 and my image was centered as such within the DIV... oh yes, I can't forget how I had to add the height to show the image... for a while I wondered where it was until I did this. I don't think the position and display are necessary.

```
background-image: url('../Images/01.png');    
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center;
position:relative;
display:block;
height:60px;
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to center an image both vertically and horizontally, is to use two containers, and apply the following properties :

### The outher container

- should have `display: table;`

### The inner container

- should have `display: table-cell;`
- should have `vertical-align: middle;`
- should have `text-align: center;`

### A demo

```css
.outer-container {
    display: table;
    width: 80%; /* can be any width */
    height: 120px; /* can be any height */
    background: #ccc;
}

.inner-container {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

.inner-container img {
    background: #fff;
    padding : 10px;
    border : 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
   <div class="inner-container">
     <img src="http://s.gravatar.com/avatar/bf4cc94221382810233575862875e687?r=x&s=50" />
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

```
IMG.displayed {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto 
}

<IMG class="displayed" src="..." alt="...">
```

Comment: doesn't handle vertical center

Answer (score 0):

Here try this out.

```css
.parentdiv {
 height: 400px;
 border: 2px solid #cccccc;
  background: #efefef;
 position: relative;
}
.childcontainer {
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
}
.childdiv {
 width: 150px;
 height:150px;
 background: lightgreen;
 border-radius: 50%;
 border: 2px solid green;
 margin-top: -50%;
 margin-left: -50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentdiv">
  <div class="childcontainer">
     <div class="childdiv">
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple and elegant solution that works for me everytime:

```
<div>
    <p style="text-align:center"><img>Image here</img></p>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't always work, e.g., in a small image with some text on its side.

Comment: I'd advise against using style attributes manually in HTML.