# Center Content horizontally and vertically with scrollbars?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div with width: 400px and height: 300px
**Inside the div I will insert some Text which should be aligned horizontaly and verticaly.**

if the text inside the div is bigger than the div, it should show the scrollbars. Here is a picture which shows what i mean:

[image: center]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works in webkit & geko & IE8 upwards. Try some of these techniques for vertical centering if you need legacy IE compatibility: http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/ OR [Vertically and Horizontally Center Image inside a Div, if you don't know Image's Size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436986/vertically-and-horizontally-center-image-inside-a-div-if-you-dont-know-images)

```
<div style="height:300px; overflow-y:auto; border:solid 1px #CCC;  width:400px;">
    <div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; height:300px; text-align:center; width:400px;">
        test
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j8vLw/
Another vertical centering technique is at http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

Answer (score 0):

you might want to use on div as a container and then put your text in another div
you might also want to check out [jscrollpane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/)

```
div.container {
overflow: auto;
text-align: center;
}



<div class="container">
<p align="center">
<h2>Heading 1</h1>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
</p>
</div>
```

Also try to set a fixed height for your container so you can get the scroll bars

```
    div.container {
max-height: 200px
}
```

The post by cronoklee works good too u might want to combine the two methods to get exactly what you want