# Image in absolute position div

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make an image center (vertically & horizontally) inside a bigger div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388180/how-to-make-an-image-center-vertically-horizontally-inside-a-bigger-div)

I have a div which is with absolute position (width/height are 100%). 
Notice, not px, percents.
Inside this div I have an image. How do I center this image in this div?

Comment: You want to center the image both vertically AND horizontally, yes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CSS:

```
/* where margin-left = {img width}/2, and margin-top= {img height}/2 */
.bigdiv {
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   position:absolute;
}
.bigdiv img {
   position:absolute;
   left:50%;
   top:50%;
   margin-left:-10px;
   margin-top:-10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="bigdiv"><img src="eg.png" /></div>
```

You could also put your margin-left, margin-top commands as a style on the img tag instead (since they're unique per image).

Comment: Your example works but add horizontal and vertical scrolls on Safari 5.0.3 (Mac OS X 10.6.6) 
My image is 100px/100px so the values of margin(left|right) are -50px
How to fix that ?

Comment: That's like the default `body` padding safari puts in, try adding CSS: `body {margin:0;padding:0;}`