# <img> in <div> won't vertical-align:middle, why?

Tags: css, image, vertical-alignment

we have CSS:

```
#left,#right{width:450px;height:450px;}
#left{position:absolute;left:20px;top:30px;}
#right{position:absolute;left:420px;top:30px;float:center;}

#left img, #right img{float:center; vertical-align:middle;cursor:pointer}
```

Image is horizotal centered, but gets top aligned (i want middle)

html looks **like**

```
<div id="media">
    <div id="left"><img/></div> <div id="right"><img/></div>
</div>
```

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

By the way, all this problem it's because i'm [displaying](http://anulekha.net/?view=Collections&Lookbook=2011) images with different resolutions :S

### EDIT

This didn't help... :(

```
#left,#right{width:450px;line-height:450px;}
#left{position:absolute;left:20px;top:30px;}

#right{position:absolute;left:420px;top:30px;float:center;}
#left img,#right img{cursor:pointer;}
```

Comment: You have two closing <img/> tags...

Comment: well 'html looks like' of corse they have respective alt, title and src attributes ;)

Comment: This post looks familiar.

There is no such thing as 'float:center' first of all.

Comment: I know, but it works anyway (float:left;) but, i'm asking about vertical ;) thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll first off need to have some height declared on `#left` or `#right` to get it to align vertically. (As it is, it has no more known space to align vertically in than the space it's taking up--so it will always appear top-aligned.)

Secondly, make sure you understand `vertical-align` correctly. Here's a good resource: http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html In short, `vertical-align` is probably not the best solution.

Comment: So what do i do if no text? seted height but same result :(

Comment: if i understood well method 2 would be like my edit?? if so, didn't help.. :( thanks!

Comment: You have to set a height *and* line-height (to the parent element, so #left or #right or #center) as well. Looks like you set a line-height, but not a height. Give that a shot.

Answer (score 4):

you can vertical align an image in a div that has no text in it by setting line-height on the on the div.  example:

```
<div style="height: 100px; line-height: 100px;">
    <img src="http://nelson-haha.com" height="50" style="vertical-align: middle;"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`vertical-align` on an image is how the text aligns to the image, the way the text wraps around the image.  Not the way the image is displayed in the `div`.

Please see this on [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388180/how-to-make-an-image-center-vertically-horizontally-inside-a-bigger-div)

Comment: i see, but my problem is that i'm playing with horzontal and vertical images.... that post only seems to help if you know dimensions already, but thanks!