# How do you center a div within a div, vertically and horizontally?

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make an image center (vertically & horizontally) inside a bigger div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388180/how-to-make-an-image-center-vertically-horizontally-inside-a-bigger-div)

So I have a div which is 300px in both height and length. I want a div which is 100px in height and width to be within that div, centered horizontally and vertically. So basically there is 100px on every side of the inner div. How do i do that?

Comment: This has been asked **to death**. Try searching. The answer is here somewhere.

Comment: true, should have looked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#big {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
#small {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 100px;
}

<div id="big">
  <div id="small"></div>
</div>
```