# Set an image in the center of DIV

Tags: css, html, centering

How to an image in the center of a DIV (both vertically and horizontally) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388180/how-to-make-an-image-center-vertically-horizontally-inside-a-bigger-div

Comment: can you be anymore vague? ;) you can set it as a background image and set `background-position: center center` ...

Comment: @Hannes This was a perfectly valid question and can actually be done a number of different ways depending on exactly what he's trying to accomplish.

Comment: The OP apparently wants to center an image horizontally and vertically inside a DIV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a go:

```
    div.wrapper{
      width:75px;
      height:75px;
    }
    img{
      width:50px;
      height:50px;
      display:block;
    /* For vertical center - margin: 0 auto;
       For horizontal center - margin: auto 0px;*/
      margin: auto auto;
    }
```

Comment: Unless mistaken, this will only work if you know the dimensions of a picture.

Comment: you're proposing a ludicrous scenario where the developers and designers of a project wouldn't be setting the sizes, or resizing uploads, and putting in zero back end work... never going to be a problem.

Comment: Sorry if you took the comment badly @Relic. This was just an observation and I'll upvote your comment for frankness. There is the case of user-uploaded images with variable proportions. Now you mention it, a back-end developer could manipulate images to add whitespace or transparency to fit given dimensions.

Comment: Oh so totally, and I hope you didn't think I was jumping down your throat... like you said, I was just being frank. I hope this helps answer future questions.

Comment: Sure. I should have added this link to go along with the comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597165/centering-dynamically-sized-images. Also, this adding whitespace has given me an idea to enhance an image-resizing script so thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

[Exactly Center an Image/Div Horizontally and Vertically](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/exactly-center-an-imagediv-horizontally-and-vertically/)

Answer (score 1):

```
background-position: center center;
```