# Centering dynamically-sized images

Tags: css, html, image, centering

I'm using a PHP script to automatically resize pictures proportionally so they fit a given height and width (ex: original picture is 200x100px, target box is 180x180px, resized image is 180x90px).

It works fine but the usual CSS tricks used to center an image inside a div seem to require you knowing the dimensions in advance.

The only workaround I've found is to define an outer div to `display:table;` and the div containing an image to `display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;text-align:center;`.

Is there another way ?

Comment: Can't you put transparent color in your php script to get a 180x180px image ?

Comment: I think the only other way to guarantee vertical centring is using JavaScript - is that acceptable in your situation?

Comment: If you'd like to use the method you allude to instead of the table-cell trick, you can use Javascript to both get the dimensions of the image and set the style of it, or return to the browser custom style rules from your PHP script.

Comment: Are there any other elements in the containing div besides the image?

Comment: @BaliBalo That's smart thinking. Yes, there's no obstacle to using PNG as the images will be small.

Comment: @Codemonkey I'm not sure. This will end up being used on a site that can have lots of photos being displayed on one page.

Comment: @jsalvy It's just the image and that's it. A span might be required to put a sprite on top of the image though to do stuff like indicate member status.

Answer (score 4):

Not the best practice text-align to align images.

> "The tricky thing about the text-align property is that you can only align text with it - you can't use it to move block-level elements like images. Some browsers will align images or tables with this property, but it's not reliable, as you've found." --[Jennifer Kyrnin, About.com](http://webdesign.about.com/od/graphics/f/blfaqtxtalgimg.htm)

- You can use the deprecated img's attribute align="center", Although you won't use. This way tags and style are mixed, and, to worsen, there are vertical and horizontal spaces around the full image.

  ```
  <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/100/150" align="center"> <-- Wrong way
  ```
- The best way to solve this is using css. Setting the image as div's background then the div's space will be your image's space and you can use margins to put it in place. You can try to use one of these others techniques [CSS Tricks's Absolute center an image](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/absolute-center-vertical-horizontal-an-image/)

CSS background-image Technique:

```css
background:url('path_to_img') center center no-repeat; /* div center */
background:url('path_to_img') center 0      no-repeat; /* div horizontal center */
background:url('path_to_img') 0      center no-repeat; /* div vertical center */
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need to use an img tag, and do not want to mess with divs with background images, you can try this method:

http://jsfiddle.net/Nz6Nm/3/

```css
.container
{
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    background-color: #FF0000;
    line-height: 180px;
    font-size: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.container img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

font-size is set to 0 to avoid weird spacing. Having line-height equal to the height of your container, causes vertical-align to work as a vertical center, at least for images.

The benefit of this is that you will be able to put your images in img tags, which is more semantically pleasing than background images. This method works when you have a known container size, but an unknown image size that you wish to center inside.

**Edit:**  Here's a link to another fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Nz6Nm/4/

You mentioned possibly needing to put text above the image, so I just wanted so show a quick way of doing it. This way adds 20px to the top. If you need to stick with the 180 x 180, then you can adjust the logic to fit.
​