# How to center vertically child elements inside div

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make an image center (vertically & horizontally) inside a bigger div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388180/how-to-make-an-image-center-vertically-horizontally-inside-a-bigger-div)

HTML code:

```
<div class="promo_tumbs col_12">
    <div class="promo_tumb"></div>
    <div class="promo_tumb"></div>
    <div class="promo_tumb"></div>
    <div class="promo_tumb"></div>
    <div class="promo_tumb"></div>
</div>
```

CSS part:

```
.promo_tumbs {
    height: 155px;
    background: #058;
}
.promo_tumb {
    height: 75px;
    width: 125px;
    background: #990000;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

How can I vertically center `.promo_tumb`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Read this article on vertical centering.

http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

If you dont wanna support IE7 or lesser then you can use `vertical-align : middle`.

Otherwise:

1. Set `display` to `table`  in `.promo_tumbs col_12`
2. Set `vertical-align` to `middle` & `display` to  `table-cell` for
       `.promo_tumb`

and it should work.

Comment: Article is quite good. Thank you for the link, it is very informativ :)

Comment: Does setting display to table suffer from the same drawbacks that comes with using actual tables?

Comment: I'm not a big fan of this method myself (I have used it once for a quick hack). But yes, i believe so.

Answer (score 4):

Will the heights (`155px` and `75px` respectively) always be fixed? In that case it'd be as simple as changing the `.promo_tumb` margin:

```
margin: 40px 10px
```

Comment: This is still in the making, so at the  moment heights are just for testing.

Comment: Well the best approach to vertical centering depends very much on which variables are known.

Comment: When designer make up his mind, I will just do the math. Thank you for your help :).

Answer (score 0):

use the `vertical-align: middle;` in the css/style for promo_thumbs.

Answer (score 0):

```
css part insert in head section..........

   <style type="text/css">
  .promo_tumbs {height: 155px; background: #058; }
  .promo_tumb {height: 75px; width: 125px; background: #990000; float: left; 

   margin: 40px 50px; 

   text-align: center; }
  </style>
```

body part coding......

```
          <div class="promo_tumbs col_12">
                <div class="promo_tumb"></div>
                <div class="promo_tumb"></div>
                <div class="promo_tumb"></div>
                <div class="promo_tumb"></div>
                <div class="promo_tumb"></div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.promo_tumbs {height: 155px; background: #058;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display:table-cell;
 }
```