# Centering image horizontally and vertically

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make an image center (vertically & horizontally) inside a bigger div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388180/how-to-make-an-image-center-vertically-horizontally-inside-a-bigger-div)

I am trying to make an image gallery on my website,
but I cannot center the image inside the div.

The CSS for the div is:

```
#animation
{
display : none;
position: absolute;
z-index:1;
background : rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
border: 0px;
}
```

And the image id is:

```
#pictures
{
...
}
```

Comment: duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388180](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388180/how-to-make-an-image-center-vertically-horizontally-inside-a-bigger-div)

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is a table cell display and `vertical align: middle;`

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/VyEzj/)

Comment: what about horizontal aligning

Comment: My fiddle includes that too, I used `margin: 0 auto;` (this only works if you declare the image as a block level element (`display: block;`)

Comment: yeah , I tried this but the things is that when I declare table cell the div will not take the (display:none) and the div won't hide.

Comment: I cant help much without context, but you could try visibility: hidden, or absolute position and throw the image off the screen with a -value on left:

Answer (score 0):

margin:auto; add autommatic margin and center the image have a try, but I need more code , could you post it?

Comment: user1538100 get the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

Put your image inside div and center it like this:
[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bb9jj/)

```
 div{
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
 margin:0px auto;
 margin-top:30px; //to pull it down
 }
```

Comment: how can you be so confirmed about margin-top:20px;

Comment: It is just an example  to position this div...

Comment: not being rude but this is a bad example

Comment: Can you please explain why is this example bad?THX!!

Comment: yes because you have settled margin-top yourself what is the parent container has a height of 1000px;

Comment: You are right I didn't see it. Damn...

Answer (score 0):

```
margin:auto;
```

it will automatically center your **div** by adding equal margin to the left and right of your **div** block element

Answer (score 0):

Check out these resources:

If you know the width of the div - [How to make an image center (vertically & horizontally) inside a bigger div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388180/how-to-make-an-image-center-vertically-horizontally-inside-a-bigger-div)

If you don't know the width of the div - http://doctype.com/css-centering-wide-image-unspecified-dimensions-div-unspecified-dimensions