# Centering a picture

Tags: jquery, html, css

I wanna center a image within a div that has overflow hidden

Like a frame and then picture no matter size are centered.

```
<div class="holder">
   <div id="frame">
      <img src="http://www.travelblog.org/Wallpaper/pix/tb_fiji_sunset_wallpaper.jpg" class="centerme"/>
   </div>
</div>​
```

See picture for more info:
[image]

standard state is how it always gonna be with overflow:hidden;

but need it to always center even its a picture 3 times bigger than the frame

*heres the JSfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/UL3qp/4/

*EDIT
Last needed is to loop this incident

Comment: everything i tried like absolute, and stuff dont really make any solution im out of idears thats why i ask, this is being used in a foreach so the backend gonna make it for over 150 items atm.

atm i just got the standard css, 1 sec then im gonna make a jsfiddle

Comment: a plain `text-align: center;` will do the trick: http://jsbin.com/ufozol/1/

Comment: no i know how to center a image im looking for a way to center it within a frame look at the jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Centering the image [with jQuery is simple](http://jsfiddle.net/UL3qp/21/) - via setting a positive or negative `margin-left` property:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var fwidth = $('#frame').width();
    var iwidth = $('#frame img').width();
    $('#frame img').css('margin-left', Math.floor((fwidth-iwidth)/2));
});
```

With only the pure CSS it can be done via [a background image css property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388180/how-to-make-an-image-center-vertically-horizontally-inside-a-bigger-div/402643#402643) instead of using the `img` tag.

Comment: btw what do i have to do if i wanna do this math with multiple pictures

Comment: Then I am glad it is useful. :) Added here a loop to center all images separately: http://jsfiddle.net/UL3qp/34/

Comment: its a frame that surround the image and then frame is overflow,

Comment: Ok, here are two its variants: http://jsfiddle.net/KSnjU/6/ or http://jsfiddle.net/KSnjU/7/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/HCabZ/2/ try out this for vertical align- center as well as right & left center

Comment: if you lower the size of your frame it wont overwrite the picture size

Comment: i need a specific frame size and the frame is overflow hidden. and within that i need the center of the image to align with the center of the frame

Answer (score 0):

Add the styles:

```
#frame{padding:15px; text-align:center}
#frame img{max-width:100%}
```

Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/HCabZ/

Comment: your frame is under the picture and not above like in the question.

Comment: this also just center the image