# Using margins to center an icon on a div

Tags: css

I am trying a method of centering an icon using margins.I am giving the icon a width in % and the height in % too.I have

```
.container{
width:600px;
height:200px;
background-color:orange;
}
img {
width:6%;
margin-left:47%;
margin-right:47%;
height:16%;
margin-top:12%;
margin-bottom:12%;
}
body{

}
```

The method centers the icon horizontally but not vertically.I wonder why this wont work

```
img {
    width:6%;
    margin-left:47%;
    margin-right:47%;
    height:16%;
    margin-top:42%;
    margin-bottom:42%;
    }
```

I also have this fiddle but the margin-top and margin-bottom i have used are random http://jsfiddle.net/thiswolf/EKWWt/

Comment: For fixed layout: http://jsfiddle.net/EKWWt/2/

Comment: Using a percentage for `margin-[top|bottom]` will give a margin that is a percentage of the *width* of the element. `margin-[top|bottom]: n%` is not what you want here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see your image because of firewall nonsense, but take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388180/how-to-make-an-image-center-vertically-horizontally-inside-a-bigger-div). Also here is my [forked fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WKvK3/).

```
.container{
    width:600px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:orange;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:138px; /*You'll have to play around with this value*/
}

img {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: I have that in a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/thiswolf/HDN4M/ but i am testing it on bootstrap.UPDATE:Works on twitter bootstrap too.

Comment: @Dev I am guessing that the height of the line height and the height of the div have to be the same?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
.container{
width:600px;
height:200px;
background-color:orange;
}
img {
margin:12% 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try just placing the icon in as a background instead. If it's a requirement that it be in the html because it's loaded dynamically, then you can use javascript to replace it as a background.

Answer (score 0):

I think the image is taking margins from the body and not from the container div.
To centre image horizontally and vertically you can set position: relative; in the container div and position: absolute; in img element. This can be one of the possible solution.

So the css can be like this...

```
.container{
  width:600px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:orange;
    position: relative;
 }
 img {
 width:6%;
 margin-left:47%;
 margin-right:47%;
 height:16%;
 margin-top:42%;
 margin-bottom:42%;
    position: absolute;
}
```