# Center Image (vertically & horizontally) inside a Div

Tags: html, css

I have a container div, and I want to show an image inside it. Image is going to be dynamic. It's dimensions could be greater/lesser than the dimensions of the div. I want to show entire image inside this div centered (horizontally and vertically) . How do I do that?

I have read few similar questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388180/how-to-make-an-image-center-vertically-horizontally-inside-a-bigger-div). But most of them talk about ways to do this given that the image dimensions are known. Also, I've got horizontal centering working with margin set to auto.

---

EDIT: adding my css styles so far, gallery container is the bigger div, and photo container is the one that wraps around the image.

```
    /* Gallery */
    #gallery-container { 
        position:absolute; 
        overflow:hidden;
        width:100%; 
        height:100%; 
        top:0; 
        left:0; 
        display:none; 
        z-index:100; 
        text-align: center;
   }


   #gallery-container .gallery-photo-container{
       position: relative;
       width:80%; 
       height:100%;
       margin: auto auto;
   }

   #gallery-container img{
       position: relative;
       max-width:100%; 
       max-height:100%;
   }
```

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vertically align an image inside a div with responsive height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516317/vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div-with-responsive-height)

Comment: its a year old question, how did you even find this?