# Align image to baseline

Tags: html, css

I need to construct a layout like the following

```
+-------+-----------------------------+-------+
|       |                             |       |
|       |                             |       |
|   A   |             B               |   C   |
|       |                             |       |
|       |                             |       |
|       |                             |       |
+-------+-----------------------------+-------+
```

In zone A I would like to put an image that shall be aligned to top right.
In zone B I would like to put an image that shall be centered (vertical & horizontal)
In zone C I would like to put an image that shall be aligned bottom left

I have the following markup.

```
<div style="float: left;">
    <img src="/images/sx.jpg" alt="sx" height="100" width="90" />
</div>
<div class="slideshow" style="float: left;">
    [...]
</div>
<div style="float: right;">
    <img src="/images/dx.jpg" alt="dx" height="100" width="90" />
</div>
```

I have tried to use CSS `vertical-align` but it does'nt work. How can I obtain what I want?
Thanks for helping

Comment: What do you want to change about this: http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/n5Qmz/ ?

Comment: @ExplosionPills: Dont understand your comment. The fiddle simply show my code....

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/QyEvg/

Comment: @Lorenzo I was just asking what you wanted changed from how your code looks now

Comment: @MichalChovanec: it seems working. but there's no other way then the 90px to center the B zone?

Comment: @ExplosionPills: Oh, I've got it now. You can change everything you like.

Comment: @Lorenzo how about like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/n5Qmz/8/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use table layout:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="a">A section</div>
    <div class="b">B section</div>
    <div class="c">C section</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.a,
.b,
.c {
    display: table-cell;
}

.a,
.c {
    width: [what you want];
}
```

Comment: I have corrected my comment. There's no other way than the 90px? Also, A and C zones are not aligned as I have asked.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <div style="float: left;">
    <img src="/images/sx.jpg" alt="sx" height="100" width="90" />
</div>
<div class="slideshow" style="padding:25% 50%; ">
    [...]
</div>
<div style="float: right; margin-top: -51.5%;">
    <img src="/images/dx.jpg" alt="dx" height="100" width="90" />
</div>
```

And, please do not ask why 51.5%  - it works pretty good (checked in Chrome), why - I do not know myself)

Comment: Good! But the A zone shall be aligned top right and C zone shall be aligned bottome left.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to horizontally and vertically align your image in the center column is using a background image.

```
background:url(yourimage.gif) no-repeat center center;
```

I would use absolute positioning to place the images on your right and left column.

```
.leftcolumn { height:400px; width:100px; float:left; position:relative; border:1px solid blue; overflow:auto; }
.leftcolumn img { position:absolute; top:0px; right:0px; }
.rightcolumn { height:400px; width:100px; float:right; position:relative; border:1px solid red; overflow:auto; }
.rightcolumn img { position:absolute; bottom:0px; left:0px; }
```

HTML Markup:

```
<div class="leftcolumn">
    <img src="/images/sx.jpg" alt="sx" height="100" width="90" />
</div>
<div class="slideshow" ></div>
<div class="rightcolumn">
    <img src="/images/dx.jpg" alt="dx" height="100" width="90" />
</div>
```

[Here is the .js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n5Qmz/3/)

Comment: This is pretty good. However I cannot use background images because in the center I have a jquery slideshow... Also A column shall be aligned top-right

Comment: Here is a good resource to center your image vert and horiz: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388180/how-to-make-an-image-center-vertically-horizontally-inside-a-bigger-div

Answer (score 1):

Is the layout fluid? Different heights? Widths aren't as hard to work with as heights

Zone A: do nothing, image will go there in the normal flow of the page

Zone B:
Option 1) If the box is fixed dimensions: use margin:100px auto 0; where 100px is the difference from the top
Option 2) If the box is fluid: use the position absolute + negative margin technique. For this example, the image would be 200px tall and 300px wide, so the margin top and margin left are -0.5 * those dimensions

```
.slideshow { position:relative; }
.slideshow img { position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%; margin:-100px 0 0 -150px; }
```

Zone C:

```
div.zoneC { position:relative; }
div.zoneC img { position:absolute; right:0; bottom:0; }
```

Comment: Sorry, I jsut noticed that Zone A is to the right. Do the same as my Zone C example, except make it top:0;

Answer (score 1):

Solution using `table-row` and `table-cell` which will allow you to use `vertical-align`.

[Display proprety MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/display).

**HTML**

```
<div class="area">
    <div style="width:250px;display:table-cell;text-align:right;">
        <img src="/images/sx.jpg" alt="sx" height="100" width="90" />
    </div>
    <div class="slideshow" style="display:table-cell;width:500px;vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;">[...]
    </div>
    <div style="display:table-cell;width:250px;vertical-align:bottom;text-align:left;">
        <img src="/images/dx.jpg" alt="dx" height="100" width="90" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.area{
    height:600px; /* some fixed height */
    display:table-row;
 }

div{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n5Qmz/8/).

Table-cell width is also *fixed*.