# Center a section that is inside a div with an image

Tags: css, html

How can I center a `<section>` vertically and horizontally inside a div?

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/F3fhK/

Comment: If the inner section has a known width and height you can use the old negative margin trick (http://jsfiddle.net/F3fhK/3/).

Comment: This does not work mate, as the images will have different heights and widths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```css
div section {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #456087;
    position: absolute;
    top:25%;
    left: 25%;
    bottom: 25%;
    right: 25%;
    opacity:0.3;
    filter:alpha(opacity=30%);
}
```

JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nfLyR/

Comment: This wont work as each image will have different height and width, so no matter what their size is, the text will be centered.

Comment: I suppose, your requirement was to make the section part as the center of the div. So irrespective of the size of the image, the section part will always be placed in the center. This is not what is required ??

Comment: I tried with images of different size and it works for me. Can you  try ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:-

1. Please refer this SO [How to make an image center (vertically & horizontally) inside a bigger div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388180/how-to-make-an-image-center-vertically-horizontally-inside-a-bigger-div)
2. You can give **margin:TOP RIGHT BOTTOM LEFT** to inner content(img, div, section etc..).