# How do I make the image appear in the center of the div?

Tags: html, css

On my site a have a div, inside the div I have different images width different width's and height's. I want the image to be in the center no matter what size or shape. Lets say the div is 200px * 200px. All images need to have min-width:100%; and min-height:100%; so that there is no white in the background. So basically I want the center of the image to be in the center of the div. How do I do it?...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>

      .div{
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
        overflow:hidden;
        box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #000;
      }

      .img{
        /*What shall I put here?*/
        min-width:100%;
        min-height:100%; 
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="div">
      <img class="img" src="img.jpg">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make an image center (vertically & horizontally) inside a bigger div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388180/how-to-make-an-image-center-vertically-horizontally-inside-a-bigger-div)

Comment: @coreyward bovine said the div was bigger than the image.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029422/image-auto-resize-to-fit-div-container

Comment: @Gavin And the technique referenced in the linked question works regardless of the size of the image relative to its container. This is a duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

You would be best setting the image as a background of the div and using setting the background position.

Comment: Suppose you have a image that is bigger that the DIV, how do you change the background-image size to make it fit?

Comment: From what the op has asked it sounds like they wand to "crop" the image and only show the centre. No need to resize.

Comment: That is a good aproach to avoid other components to move on they relative position if the images are larger than the container, if you already know the images you're displaying are not larger that container i think you can still use <div align="center"> to make it work.

Comment: @Israelm, it is bad to use attribute "align" at div because it is deprecated: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_div_align.asp. Also, it does not center vertically.

Comment: It dose not work with some images, I get a white area around the div. I need the image to take up all the space. the width or the height must be 100% of the div's size.

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate question. The answer, as referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388180/how-to-make-an-image-center-vertically-horizontally-inside-a-bigger-div), is to display the image as a CSS `background-image` rather than using an `img` element and set it to display in the center:

```
div.with-background-image { 
  background: url(/path/to/image.jpg) no-repeat center center;
}
```

To ensure that your image is as least as large as its “containing” element you can use the [`background-size` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fbackground-size), which accepts a number of different properties. The one you want is `cover`, which instructs the rendering engine to stretch the image so both dimensions of the image are at least equal to that of the element:

```
div.with-background-image {
  background: url(/path/to/image.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```