# Center align img css

Tags: html, css

How, do I get the images to center left and right?

Have tried a few different things but nothing want to work with this...

CSS: (not working)

```
body,html {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

img {
    float: left;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    width:auto;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

[jsfiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5q7jrwha/1/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make an image center (vertically & horizontally) inside a bigger div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388180/how-to-make-an-image-center-vertically-horizontally-inside-a-bigger-div) and a multitude of others.

Comment: None of the answers explain why the CSS doesn't work. It's all "do this" and "do that."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete your `float: left;`, `margin` and insert `margin: 0 auto;`.

Answer (score 1):

You also can set `display:inline-block;` to `img` and add `text-align:center;` to the parents. 
Also set `height:auto;` to keep responsive behaviour. See the fiddle below for all modifies i would do : http://jsfiddle.net/5q7jrwha/2/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/sq6xwfcy/

```
body, html {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
img {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
img {
   max-height: 100%;
   max-width: 100%;
   width:auto;
   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sq6xwfcy/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Delete `max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%;`
or `width:auto;` or use max-size in pixels `height: ""px; width: ""px;` 
Delete `float: left; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`
use `margin: 0 auto;`