# How do I center an image vertically using div?

Tags: html, css

I am currently centring an image in the horizontal using:

```
.centeredImage
    {
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    }

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
   <title>My Site</title>
   <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

   <p class="centeredImage"><img id ="img" src="smallslide1.png"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

This works fine but I want to centre it vertically too. Not sure how to do about this. I tired to wrap it in a separate div

```
.centeredVert{
    vertical-align: middle }

}
```

but this didn't do anything. could someone give me some pointers on how to do this please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make an image center (vertically & horizontally) inside a bigger div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388180/how-to-make-an-image-center-vertically-horizontally-inside-a-bigger-div)

Comment: I recently stumbled upon http://howtocenterincss.com/ which basically is a multiple choice site about centering in CSS :-)

Comment: This just isn't what vertical-align does. It really only aligns things in relation to a line of text, not the parent div http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the absolute positioning trick on the image itself:

```css
.centeredImage img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<p class="centeredImage">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100">
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#img{      
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) 
}
```

Here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cmzr7mq8/).

Comment: You can clean up the CSS, you don't need the padding and the margin-right properties, take them out and your technique works equally well.