# Align images in vertical center of Div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I vertically align my images in center of a div? What I have right now is looks like this:
[image: current state]

As you can see the last image  is correctly centered vertically, I want to place my other two images in same manner as 3rd image. My code:

```
    <!-- container -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="banner-text">
        <h3>Services</h3>
        <p>Ut mollis rhoncus porttitor. Nulla facilisi. Nulla eget est fringilla, malesuada ligula non, scelerisque enim. Fusce dui ex, accumsan at viverra nec, suscipit eget tortor.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="banner-bottom-grids">
        <div class="col-md-4 banner-bottom-grid">
            <div class="services-icon">
                <span ><img src="images/nomobile1.png"  aria-hidden="true" /></span>
            </div>
            <h4>Aliquam nulla mauris</h4>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply Ipsum has been the industry's text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 banner-bottom-grid red">
            <div class="services-icon">
                <span ><img src="images/remind1.png"  aria-hidden="true" /></span>
            </div>
            <h4>Mauris pellentesque</h4>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply Ipsum has been the industry's text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 banner-bottom-grid green">
            <div class="services-icon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large glyphicon-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </div>
            <h4>Praesent vitae quam</h4>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply Ipsum has been the industry's text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
    </div>  
</div>
<!-- //container -->
```

Comment: Your images all appear to be centred in their respective divs, Could you please be more specific as to how you would like them to appear?

Comment: can you see the 3rd image ? the thumb image (which is basically not an image ) `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large glyphicon-thumbs-up"` see this image is more centered then other 2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an image center (vertically & horizontally) inside a bigger div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388180/how-to-make-an-image-center-vertically-horizontally-inside-a-bigger-div)

Comment: alright @EddieHart your link's answer says `#demo {
    background: url(bg_apple_little.gif) no - repeat center center;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}` but can you explain where to put this ?

Comment: @remyboys I see what you mean.  Did you try <div style="vertical-align:middle"></div> in your parent div?

Comment: hey man  @Aserian you mean something like this ?? `<div style="vertical-alig‌​n:middle" ><div class="services-icon">
                <span ><img src="images/nomobile1.png"  aria-hidden="true" /></span>
            </div> </div>` ???

Comment: @remyboys  Yeah, your code would look like: <div style="vertical-align:middle;" class="col-md-4 banner-bottom-grid">
            <div class="services-icon">
                <span ><img src="images/nomobile1.png"  aria-hidden="true" /></span>
            </div>
            <h4>Aliquam nulla mauris</h4>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply Ipsum has been the industry's text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
        </div>

If that doesn't work, try moving it into the inner div.

Comment: no man both didnt worked @Aserian

Comment: Looks like my comment was a little naive, try this: http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html