# position: absolute not working as expected

Tags: html, css, sass

I have an element with an image inside and I want to center it.
I'm using position: absolute but it does not work properly.
Here is the code:

```
<div class="wraper">
  <div class="main"><img src="image.jpg" alt=""></div>
</div>

.wrapper {
  position: relative;

  .main {
     margin-top: -157px;
     margin-left: -157px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     width: 314px;
     height: 314px;
     line-height: 314px;
     background: #000;
     border-radius: 50%;
     text-align: center;

     img {
       vertical-align: middle;
     }
  }
}
```

And here is the image:
[image]

Comment: You want to center the image inside the div?

Comment: Yes, but .wrapper div is position: relative

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an image center (vertically & horizontally) inside a bigger div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388180/how-to-make-an-image-center-vertically-horizontally-inside-a-bigger-div)

Comment: Why do you want to use absolute positioning for centering? There are better ways available - do some research.

Comment: Try adding `text-align: center` to your div's CSS

Comment: There's a lot more wrong than just the syntax

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the syntax (other than the misspelled class name). It's SCSS, not CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You are using misspelled class name in HTML:

```
<div class="wraper">
               ^^---- it should be wrapper
```

And you will need to add `height: 100%` as well. i.e:

```
html,
body,
.wrapper {height: 100%;}
```

```css
html,
body,
.wrapper {height: 100%;}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.main {
  margin-top: -157px;
  margin-left: -157px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 314px;
  height: 314px;
  line-height: 314px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main"><img src="image.jpg" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the height of all ancestors to `100%` otherwise they will collapse to zero and the result will look like your screenshot.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zq16p3vd/)

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin:0;
}
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;

  .main {
     margin-top: -157px;
     margin-left: -157px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     width: 314px;
     height: 314px;
     line-height: 314px;
     background: #000;
     border-radius: 50%;
     text-align: center;

     img {
       vertical-align: middle;
     }
  }
}
```

None SCSS version:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin:0;
}
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper .main {
     margin-top: -157px;
     margin-left: -157px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     width: 314px;
     height: 314px;
     line-height: 314px;
     background: #000;
     border-radius: 50%;
     text-align: center;
  }

.wrapper .main img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="">  </div>
</div>
```