# Specific issue in vertical/horizontal centering inside a div

Tags: html, css, image

In the following code, I'm trying to vertical/horizontal center the image inside the red block. Note that after the block there is a centered text.

I guess it is simple, but I've tried many solutions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12471484/4927984), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21102058/4927984), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12343082/4927984), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/114549/4927984), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4753609/4927984)), it still does not work as expected...

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3mkfza5u/)

```css
.parent {
  text-align: center;
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
}

.child {
  background-color: red;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <img src="http://dlg.galileo.usg.edu/images/Historic_Architecture_and_Landscapes.gif" />
  </div>
  <p>Legend of the block</p>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <img src="http://dlg.galileo.usg.edu/images/Historic_Architecture_and_Landscapes.gif" />
  </div>
  <p>Legend of the block</p>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <img src="http://dlg.galileo.usg.edu/images/Historic_Architecture_and_Landscapes.gif" />
  </div>
  <p>Legend of the block</p>
</div>
```

**Constraints:**

I display several blocks, and the `width:33%` and `float: left` comes from Bootstrap classes and can **not** be deleted.

Comment: May I know why it is downvoted? :o

Comment: Always try to use Flexbox to align block items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use below CSS Code for this

```
.child {
    background-color: red;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

for Updated Fiddle [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/3mkfza5u/1/)

```css
.parent {
  text-align: center;
  width: calc(100% /3);
  float: left;
}
.child {
  background-color: red;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <img src="http://dlg.galileo.usg.edu/images/Historic_Architecture_and_Landscapes.gif" />
  </div>
  <p>Legend of the block</p>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <img src="http://dlg.galileo.usg.edu/images/Historic_Architecture_and_Landscapes.gif" />
  </div>
  <p>Legend of the block</p>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <img src="http://dlg.galileo.usg.edu/images/Historic_Architecture_and_Landscapes.gif" />
  </div>
  <p>Legend of the block</p>
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3mkfza5u/ As you can see, it makes the legend failed.