# How to implement turn.js on responsive images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, turn.js

I am struggling to implement [`turn.js` library](http://www.turnjs.com/) on my responsive images. I thought that using JS libraries is easy but adapting the JS library to developer's code seems to be harder than expected.

I have written some code to show how I want the final result to look like - there is some `#headings` div followed by `#fbook` div which contains `.fbookImg` images. In order to make the code less messy and more readable for You, I have decided to put only one image in it.

**HTML**:

```
<div id="headings">
</div>
<div id="fbook">
  <img class="fbookImg" src="http://oi67.tinypic.com/30ue0bp.jpg" />
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#headings {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid black 1px;
}

#fbook {
  width: 100%;
  border: dashed blue 1px;
}

.fbookImg {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto !important;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

In the JS section I have some code to make images more responsive

**JS** (turn.js and jQuery are already linked):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var a = window.innerHeight - 100;
    $('#fbook').css('height',a);
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    var b = window.innerHeight - 100;
    $('#fbook').css('height',b);
});
```

FYI here is the fiddle/codepen: http://codepen.io/Janos/pen/wdwzVK

---

I tried to put more `.fbookImg` images into `#fbook` div ...

```
<div id="fbook">
  <img class="fbookImg" src="http://oi67.tinypic.com/30ue0bp.jpg" />
  <img class="fbookImg" src="http://oi66.tinypic.com/jkk13o.jpg" />
</div>
```

... and put there the appropriate `turn.js` code according to the example on their official website ...

```
$("#fbook").turn({
    display: "single",
    autoCenter: true
});
```

... BUT the final result ([fiddle here](http://codepen.io/Janos/pen/jmNVMm)) is far away from what I wanted, it doesn't seem to respect my default styling at all and no effect is applied.

Answer (score 2):

I would go for the [**5th version of turn.js**](http://turnjs.com/catalog/#page/1)

They also support responsiveness way better now! Check it out!

**How to fix you problem:**

Get `height` and `width` of the `element` where your `img` should be shown in and apply it to your `img`! You can also do it as `background-image` described [**here**](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) to fit the outer `element`!

Comment: I don´t think the 5th release is available yet. Back to coding ... Why can´t I just let the images to have default sizes specified in css? What is the problem? 

Besides, I am going to add more than 10 images so I think making them with ´background-image´ is not the best choice.

Comment: I successfully used the 5th version in one of my client projects and it works like a charm. For more info on how to resize images see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388180/how-to-make-an-image-center-vertically-horizontally-inside-a-bigger-div?rq=1). No duplicate posting on this.