# place image vertical in middle

Tags: css

Hi how do i place this image vertical in the middle of the div?
The height of the header is different when you are login or logout!

```
<div class="header">
  <nav class="header-content columns" data-topbar role="navigation"> 
    <div class="logo-area">
      <?php echo logo_header(); ?>
    </div>
    <section class="header-content-section">

    </section>
  </nav>
</div>
```

How to set up the css that the image will stay vertical centered?
.header-content .logo-area {

}
.header-content .logo-area img {

}

Thanks

Comment: Theres a great answer to that question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388180/how-to-make-an-image-center-vertically-horizontally-inside-a-bigger-div

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by putting an auto margin on the left and right, but you need to display your image as block, so it occupies all the space in the container.

```
.header-content .logo-area img { 
  display: block; 
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: This do anything

Comment: It depends on the size of your divs surrounding the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```
.header-content .logo-area {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.header-content .logo-area img {
  width:250px;
  height:250px;
}
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/q59wv9ew/2/

Comment: for horizontal yes not for vertical

Comment: See this topic sir https://forums.osclass.org/themes-26/how-to-center-a-image-vertical-in-css/