# Can't Centre Image In Div

Tags: css, jsx

```
<div style={{textAlign:'center !important',margin:'0 auto !important'}}>
     <img className="lazy" src={require("../images/dragonfire.jpg")} style={{display:'block !important', margin:'auto !important', position:'absolute', left:'0',right:'0',top:'0',bottom:'0',height:'40em',width:'40em'}}/>
</div>
```

I have looked through a lot of posts here and external sites as well on this topic and it seems that nothing is working. I have a big image that I just want it to be centered in the screen view. The div is a background for the banner on a page. I can get it to the right size but it just shows the left half of the image, I cannot get it to center and just cut off the left and right sides depending on the sides of the screen.

Comment: you are usning fixed widith/height .. remove them

Comment: Position absolute is bugging. You want the image part of the flow. The `absolute` is taking it out the flow.

Comment: https://ibb.co/dNoUiT I have tried both these things but it's still messed up in the same way @TemaniAfif

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an image center (vertically & horizontally) inside a bigger div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388180/how-to-make-an-image-center-vertically-horizontally-inside-a-bigger-div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing:
`left:'0',right:'0',top:'0',bottom:'0'`

This is fixing the position of your image to the top-left corner.

Also as @Daniel has mentioned in the comments, change the `position:absolute` to `relative` since it restricts the flow of the content inside the div.

Here is the working model:

```css
div{
  background: red;  /*Just for clarrification case*/
  textAlign: center !important;
  margin: 0 auto !important;
}

img{
 display: block !important;
 margin: auto !important;
 position: relative;
 height: 100px;
 width:100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
     <img className="lazy" src="http://mxtrianz.me/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/small-pictures-20-the-data-lab.jpg"/>
</div>
```

P.S. Comment on your code: Please try using external or internal styling and refuse using inline styling as it reduces the readability of your code.